# EJB - Unable to execute results from ServiceLayer

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, ejb-3.0

When I execute from DAO layer(ProjectDAOImpl), I'am able to see the results from database.

However when I execute from results from Service layer, I'am getting null pointer exceptions.

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>   ProjectServiceImpl.fetchProjects(ProjectServiceImpl.java:25)
>   ProjectServiceImpl.main(ProjectServiceImpl.java:36)

How can I resolve this issue?

**DAO Layer Interface and Class**

```
@Remote
public interface ProjectDAO {


    List<Project> fetchProjectDetail();
}

@Stateless
public class ProjectDAOImpl implements ProjectDAO {
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = 
        Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("projects");    

    public ProjectDAOImpl() {
    }

    public List<Project> fetchProjectDetail() {
        List<Project> listProject = new ArrayList<Project>();
            listProject = 
                    getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Project.findProjects").getResultList();
        return listProject;
    }

    private EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }
}
```

**Service Layer Interface and Class**

```
@Remote
public interface ProjectService {

    List<Project> fetchProjectDetail();
}

@Stateless
public class ProjectServiceImpl implements ProjectService {
    private ProjectDAO projectDAO;

    public ProjectServiceImpl() {
    }

    @EJB
    public void setProjectDAO(ProjectDAO projectDAO) {
        this.projectDAO = projectDAO;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/projects")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Project> fetchProjects() {
    return getProjectDAO().fetchProjectDetail();
    }

    public ProjectDAO getProjectDAO() {
        return projectDAO;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        ProjectServiceImpl projectServiceImpl = new ProjectServiceImpl();
        projectServiceImpl.fetchProjects();

    }
}
```

Comment: By creating objects via `new` you bypass EJB container and therefore you do not utilize container services like injection etc. If you need to run your application from `main` method take a look at EJB embedded container.

Comment: @slwk so the exception I am having is due to running application from main method?

Comment: In short: yes. I assume that you do not use any app server like Glassfish, JBoss etc? This way your beans aren't run inside EJB container. If you want to run from `main` method you have to manually set dependencies in service layer (DAO etc.).

Comment: See this link to see how you can run EJB in java SE: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/EJBLiteAndJPAInJavaSE/EJBLiteAndJPAInJavaSE.html

Comment: @slwk I have tried invoking fetchProjects method from outside, i.e. from browser, however same error still persists.